# Error de selección con productos variables con muchas variaciones

Tags: wordpress

Tengo una tienda online en woocommerce. hay varios productos con 40-50 variaciones que no están funcionando bien del lado del cliente.

Por ejemplo en un producto "polo" que tiene tallas y colores, supongamos que tengo las siguiente variaciones:

1. Talla: L / Color: Rojo
2. Talla S / Color: Verde
3. Talla S / Color: Azul.

Si el cliente selecciona "Talla: S", solo debería mostrar los colores verde y azul, pero no pasa eso y aparece el color rojo también, y al seleccionar le color rojo aparece que la combinación NO EXISTE, y es obvio, porque dicha combinación no existe pero no debería ser posible elegir dicha combinación.

¿Alguien sabe a qué se deba el problema y cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré encontrar la solución con lo siguiente:

Ir al archivo "functions.php".
Ir al final del archivo y agregar el siguiente código:

```php
function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold(
  $qty, $product
) {
  return 60;
}

add_filter(
  'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold',
  'custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold',
  10, 2
);
```

Cambiar el 60 de return, por el máximo de variaciones que tengan. En mi caso el máximo es 55, por eso le pongo 60, por un tema de redondeo.

En caso de tener child theme. Debe editar el functions.php del child theme.